# onsite booking for expedia by rest api calling using curl post

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Onsite booking process now i am using rest api calling to get the data about booking process.But now the problem is that when I set the form url is :-

```
$url = 'https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/res?
minorRev=99
&cid=55505
&sig=1893d9f7e3e9fbd3f8a36f43cd61287d
&apiKey=1bn8n4or4tjajq23fe4l6m18lp
&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
&customerIpAddress=223.30.152.118
&customerSessionId=e80df6de9008af772cfb48a389465415
&locale=en_US
&currencyCode=USD
&hotelId=106347
&arrivalDate=10/30/2015
&departureDate=11/01/2015
&supplierType=E
&rateKey=469e1aff-49de-4944-a64d-25d96ccde3aa
&roomTypeCode=200127420
&rateCode=200706716
&chargeableRate=257.20
&room1=2,5,7
&room1FirstName=test
&room1LastName=testers
&room1BedTypeId=23
&room1SmokingPreference=NS
&email=test@yourSite.com
&firstName=tester
&lastName=testing
&homePhone=2145370159
&workPhone=2145370159
&creditCardType=CA
&creditCardNumber=5401999999999999
&creditCardIdentifier=123
&creditCardExpirationMonth=11
&creditCardExpirationYear=2015
&address1=travelnow
&city=Bellevue
&stateProvinceCode=WA
&countryCode=US
&postalCode=98004';
```

and when i manually posted the data it will get the response But when I am using curl to post the url which i have posted previous it will face the error.
My curl code is :-

```
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
$header[] = "Content-length: 0";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

After posting data i will get the response

```
{"HotelRoomReservationResponse":{"EanWsError":{"itineraryId":-1,"handling":"UNRECOVERABLE","category":"EXCEPTION","exceptionConditionId":-1,"presentationMessage":"TravelNow.com cannot service this request.","verboseMessage":"Exception Caught: null"},"customerSessionId":"8ab1d482-f968-49d2-a429-a1cbab748fe5"}}
```

So i will get that error repeatedly. Please help me how i can find the right data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are parsing the parameters in the url they need to be given in the body see thetop of this page: http://developer.ean.com/docs/book-reservation/examples/rest-reservation/

Not sure how you do this in PHP but you can use -d on the command line